# MultiJson::DecodeError: 399: unexpected token at

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, json, activeresource, activesupport

This is my code

```
class Project < ActiveResource::Base
  self.site = "https://xyz.unfuddle.com/api/v1"
  def get_tickets
    ticket_array = []
    Project.all.each do |project|
      project.get(:tickets).each do |ticket|
        #save ticket or something
      end
    end
  end   
end
```

The error occurs in project.get(:tickets)

```
lexical error: invalid character inside string.
 16           ": "There is text that shouldn^Zt be there on the DVD/Blu-ray
 17                      (right here) ------^
```

How can I check before get if the returned text has only valid characters  ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to *get* the data anyways. otherwise you won't be able to check it for validity. that's why i would just add a try-catch-block and rescue the specific error.